# Is the universal cover of a classifying space always $\mathbb{R}^n$ if it is finite dimensional?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, classifying-spaces

If $G$ is a discrete group, and if $BG$ can be represented by a (finite dimensional) manifold, is it always true that $EG$ can be chosen to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n?$

I'm guessing the answer is no, but the fact that the Whitehead manifold satisfies $W\times\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ does make me wonder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $k$-manifold $M$ represents $BG$ if and only if $\pi_1(M) \cong G$ and $\widetilde{M}$, the universal cover of $M$, is contractible ($\widetilde{M}$ represents $EG$). If $M$ has boundary, we can choose a different representative which doesn't have boundary (namely $M\setminus \partial M$ which is homotopy equivalent to $M$). From now on, we will suppose $M$ has no boundary.

Note that $\widetilde{M}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^k$. If $k \leq 2$, then in fact $\widetilde{M}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ by the classification of such manifolds. This is no longer true when $k > 2$, e.g. if $G$ is trivial, then $BG = EG$ is represented by the Whitehead manifold $W$.

We say a topological space $X$ is *simply connected at infinity* if for any compact subset $C \subset X$, there is a compact set $D$ with $C \subset D \subset X$ such that the induced map $\pi_1(X\setminus D) \to \pi_1(X\setminus C)$ is the zero map. This property is invariant under homeomorphisms.

**Example:** $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k > 2$ is simply connected at infinity. To see this, just take $D$ to be a large closed ball containing $C$, then $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^k\setminus D) \cong \pi_1(S^{k-1}) = 0$, so the map $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^k\setminus D) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^k\setminus C)$ is the zero map.

**Non-Example:** The Whitehead manifold $W$.

This is how one sees that $W$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. When $k > 2$, all such examples take this form, i.e. an open contractible $k$-manifold with $k > 2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ if and only if it is simply connected at infinity, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275552/21564).

Now consider $N := M\times\mathbb{R}$. We have $\pi_1(N) \cong \pi_1(M) \cong G$ and $\widetilde{N} = \widetilde{M}\times\mathbb{R}$ so $\widetilde{N}$ is contractible and hence $N$ also represents $BG$. Furthermore, $\widetilde{N}$ is simply connected at infinity, see Proposition $2.2$ of [*The Piecewise Linear Structure of Euclidean Space*](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Empowell/stallings-structures-of-euclidean-space.pdf) by Stallings. Therefore $\widetilde{N}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ - note, the same trick shows why $W\times\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

That is, if $BG$ can be represented by a finite-dimensional manifold $M$, then it can be represented by a finite-dimensional manifold $N$ such that $\widetilde{N}$, the corresponding representative of $EG$, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (namely $N = M\times\mathbb{R}$ and $n = \dim M + 1$).

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not clear to me that this answers my question, since being simply connected at infinity isn't invariant under homotopy equivalences. For example, the Whitehead manifold is a classifying space for the trivial group $\{e\},$ and its universal cover is still just the Whitehead manifold, but any Euclidean space can serve as the universal bundle as well.

Comment: "It follows from Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture that the same is true when =3" is true only assuming that $M$ is compact and the question makes no such assumption.
.

Comment: @JLA: I misunderstood your question at first. I have edited to show that your question has a positive answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike: You're right, I was implicitly assuming compactness at that point. I have reformulated my answer and removed that unnecessary statement.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This is a great answer.